# Lazarus breakpoint not stopping

Tags: breakpoints, lazarus, freepascal

I'm new to Lazarus, but I've been working with Delphi for a long time.
In Delphi it is possible to add breakpoints, and when at runtime with debug (F9) the program stops at the point and I can run step by step by typing F8 viewing the values of the variables.
In Lazarus, I believe that I did not do something because it is not working.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Debugger breakpoints should work fine in Lazarus.  Does the problem persist if you do a Run | Build from Lazarus's main menu?

Comment: Hi, tks for your answer. I tested, before F9, I used shift-f9 (build) and then F9 again (would that be what you say?). The problem continues.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have enabled generation debuging information.

Project -> Project Options -> Debugging:
Generate Debugging Info for GDB

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to Lazarus also from a long history with Delphi. This is just what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me once in Delphi, not in Lazarus.

If you have Notepad++ then open your source file in Notepad++. On the main bar click on the *Show All Characters* button. You will then see that most lines end with `CRLF` (carriage return / line feed) but the one line where you are trying to break does not, it only ends with `LF`. Replace them with `CRLF`, save, reopen your file on Lazarus and give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

1- Close all forms and tabs

2- Exit IDE

3- Openup IDE

4- Cleanup and Build

5- Open your forms

This should work on most IDEs.

*Quote*